# Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server

Tags: mysql, meteor, sequelize.js

`Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`

Im on ubuntu with the latest mysql db using node, meteor.js framework and mysql npm package. On suspicion that my app needs administer rights (sudo), since mysql also requires sudo, I try and start the app as sudo which is when I get this warning:

jk@jk-Aspire-E5-521:~/Documents/garlic$ sudo meteor
[sudo] password for jk:

You are attempting to run Meteor as the 'root' superuser. If you are
developing, this is almost certainly *not* what you want to do and will likely
result in incorrect file permissions. However, if you are running this command
in a build process (CI, etc.), or you are absolutely sure you know what you are
doing, set the METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER environment variable or pass
--allow-superuser to proceed.

Even with METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER or --allow-superuser, permissions in your app
directory will be incorrect if you ever attempt to perform any Meteor tasks as
a normal user. If you need to fix your permissions, run the following command
from the root of your project:

sudo chown -Rh  .meteor/local

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1507#issuecomment-242885003

This appears to be mysql bug, restart the server after change. Changing password is unlikely to solve the issue.